# Не получается передать текст из инпут (inputname) в поле по клику кнопки (next)

Tags: jquery

Нужно чтобы после ввода текста в инпут по клику на кнопку (`next`) появлялось поле, в котором написан текст из инпута.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#task1')
    .css('display', 'none');

  function change() {
    (function() {
      var text = $('#inputname').text();
      $('#taskname').val(text);
    })
  }

  $('#next')
    .click(function() {
      $('#empty-list').css('display', 'none');
      $('#task1').css('display', 'block');
      change()
    })

  $('#dlt')
    .click(function() {
      $('#task1').css('display', 'none');
      $('#empty-list').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="taskname" name="" value="">
<button id="next">Далее</button>
<button id="dlt">Свернуть</button>
<div id="inputname">Тут какой-то текст</div>
<div id="task1"></div>
<div id="empty-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема здесь - внутренняя функция только объявляется но никогда не вызывается.

```
function change() {
    (function() {
      var text = $('#inputname').text();
      $('#taskname').val(text);
    })
}
```

Если использовалась `IIS` для имитации пространства имен - то надо запустить:

```
function change() {
    (function() {
      var text = $('#inputname').text();
      $('#taskname').val(text);
    })()
}
```

Однако это уже устарелая практика. Самовызывающуюся функцию можно совсем убрать и вместо var использовать `let`. `let` в отличие от `var` ограничивает область видимости кода блоком текущего кода - {} , т.е переменная `text` больше нигде не будет доступна.
Если объективных причин нет, то лучше так:

```
function change() {
    let text = $('#inputname').text();
    $('#taskname').val(text);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#task1')
    .css('display', 'none');

  function change() {
    let text = $('#inputname').text();
    $('#taskname').val(text);
  }

  $('#next')
    .click(function() {
      $('#empty-list').css('display', 'none');
      $('#task1').css('display', 'block');
      change()
    })

  $('#dlt')
    .click(function() {
      $('#task1').css('display', 'none');
      $('#empty-list').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="taskname" name="" value="">
<button id="next">Далее</button>
<button id="dlt">Свернуть</button>
<div id="inputname">Тут какой-то текст</div>
<div id="task1"></div>
<div id="empty-list"></div>
```

Comment: "*и вместо var использовать let*", можно я в очередной раз холивар на эту тему устрою?  Хотя‥ не буду, но вам было бы полезно дополнить объяснением почему, возможно случайному человеку, читающему ваш ответ, это будет полезно.

Comment: В данном случае абсолютно не важно будет ли `var` или `let`

Comment: для читабельности - когда на 100% уверен, что переменная ни на что не повлияет. А так - был же завернут же зачем-то этот кусок кода в функцию.

Comment: @Kjuri, этот кусок кода, в текущем виде не зачем было заворачивать. Эта обертка тоже ни на что не влияла.